# Deleting temporary decrypted files in PHP

Tags: php, file, encryption, content-management-system, delete-file

I am building my first (crude) content management system.
Users have the ability to upload/store files (pdf, doc, xls, etc...). The files are encrypted with mcrypt. I also have a pdf/document viewer, so users can browse their files without downloading them. But I am having issues working with the encrypted files.

As of now, when a user clicks on a file, a php script decrypts a copy to a folder for the plugin to access. Obviously, I need a way to delete these decrypted files after viewing. I am currently trying to do it via PHP, but am having trouble delaying the script long enough for the plugin to load the file. Is this even the best way to do it? Would a cron job be better, for example?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend directing the plugin to the URL of a PHP script that directly serves the decrypted content to the browser. This way you can avoid temporary files entirely.

As with any question concerning security, the question is what you are trying to defend against. Are you concerned about the cleartext content exposed on the server? Or are you more concerned about users guessing temporary filenames and accessing content they should not be accessing? In the latter case, sufficiently strong (as strong as the weaker of user authentication and crypto keys) random filenames that get expired by a cronjob should be enough. In the former case, see my initial recommendation and take special care protecting the keys on the server.

Comment: I think that would be ideal. I'm not quite sure how to go about decrypting content to the plugin without creating the file. Is that something you can elaborate on without needing to know my entire encryption setup?

Comment: As for the second point, my concern is in fact the content being exposed on the server. Most users have full access to all files, so no worries there.